# How do I take SELECTed output and write it to a new TABLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, select-insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert data from to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803839/insert-data-from-to-a-table)

From the main Tax table, I want to be able to do a computation and write the output into a new table.

```
select zipcode, sum(A00100)/sum(N1) as 'avg_agi' from taxbyzip2008 group by zipcode;
```

The new table to be named avgagi will have two fields (columns), the zipcode and avg_agi.

I know how to create a new table, but I don't know how to take the output from the above select and have it written to the new table avgagi and populate it with zipcode and avg_agi. Thanks!

Comment: @Jocelyn I don't see a duplicate. Are you sure?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Look at the accepted answer, using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. Just like the answers on this page.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate in my opinion. The example here is much more straight-forward and easier to understand.

Comment: The essential question in both cases is identical: how do I make a table out of the results of a SELECT query. There are actually several duplicates of this question, and I do think others were better stated yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do your create table and then

```
insert into avgagi
select zipcode, sum(A00100)/sum(N1) as 'avg_agi' from taxbyzip2008 group by zipcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into avgagi (zipcode, avg_agi)
select zipcode, sum(A00100)/sum(N1) as 'avg_agi' from taxbyzip2008 group by zipcode;
```